# C# error casting int type

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to get some values from database but I got this exception:
[image]

the type of the column "id" in database is `Ineger`:

```
CREATE TABLE crs_categorie_taux
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  designation character varying(225),
  taux double precision,
  CONSTRAINT crs_categorie_taux_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and I declare it as `int` in my C# code:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns are zero-based, this means you need to use

```
cat.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
```

You also need to decrease indexes for other columns by 1 as well.